# Couldn't Run Python Code from JavaScript using Eel

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

So for a good time I was searching for a way to run a Python script directly from JavaScript and that was when I found something called [Python-Eel](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel), which is supposed to do that. So I followed [the Hello World  example](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel?tab=readme-ov-file#eello-world). I built with a HTML, in which after I click a button, the Python script runs, but I keep getting and an error in my browser console saying that "Eel" is not defined.

I included this line in the HTML as the documentation suggests:

```
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”/eel.js”></script>
```

from [Exposing Functions](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel?tab=readme-ov-file#exposing-functions) in the Git repository

Comment: Did you figure this out? I see you're asking other questions on StackOverflow about why CSS is not being applied in your Eel project (which makes me believe you're past this particular issue). If this is no longer relevant, can you either Accept an answer or delete the question so that it no longer appears in my queue of no accepted answers? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To my google search, that's not what Python-Eel does. Its job to be used is a Electron-like tool for Python, NOT to make web apps have Python in them.

If you want python in a browser, please consider making a web app with [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) or look into [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide)

Comment: yes thats the idea i want to build a python project that has a nice ui so i went with html and css for the design however i still need python for the backend because in the end its a python project not a web project and using electron js with python is not easy and really tricky

Comment: eel is supposed to help me however i cant get pass that error saying eel is not defined

Comment: You cant import it as a js file, its is it own thing. NOT a addon to electron.